# How to decode a KTX2 texture using KTX2Decoder from Babylon.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, decode, babylonjs

I want to decode a texture in .ktx2 format and then convert it to .png in Node.js. I tried using the [KTX2Decoder](https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/tree/master/packages/tools/ktx2Decoder) from Babylon.js, but I haven't had any success.

This is what I'm doing:

```
const ktx2decoder = require("babylonjs-ktx2decoder");
const fs = require('fs');

const data = fs.readFileSync("./image.ktx2");

const a = new ktx2decoder.KTX2Decoder();
a.decode(data, {
  astc: false,
  bptc: true,
  s3tc: true,
  pvrtc: false,
  etc2: false,
  etc1: false,
}).then(b => console.log(b))
```

And this is what I'm getting:

```
{
  width: 4096,
  height: 4096,
  transcodedFormat: 36492,
  mipmaps: [ { data: null, width: 4096, height: 4096 } ],
  isInGammaSpace: true,
  hasAlpha: true,
  transcoderName: 'MSCTranscoder',
  errors: 'ReferenceError: importScripts is not defined\n' +
    'ReferenceError: importScripts is not defined\n' +
    '    at C:\\Users\\canor\\Desktop\\ktx\\node_modules\\babylonjs ktx2decoder\\babylon.ktx2Decoder.js:1:14029\n' +
    '    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n' +
    '    at async Promise.all (index 0)\n'
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I appreciate any help.